# How to use the same bean in two different spring contexts?

Tags: spring

I have two spring contexts and I need to use the same bean in both of them. Is there a way to share a bean between two contexts without making a parent context?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think what you want is a good idea. If you have the *same* bean in two contexts, then *which context manages the bean's lifecycle?* By having a common parent owning the bean, you have a clear, unambiguous answer to that important question: the bean belongs to the parent context.

Now, if you know the beans will belong to context A and only want to bind them to some name in context B, I guess you could hack some kind of "guest" bean factory or whatever, that  does something like:

Java:

```
public class GuestBeanFactory {
    private ApplicationContext guestBeanContext;

    @Inject
    public void setGuestBeanContext(ApplicationContext guestBeanContext) {
        this.guestBeanContext = guestBeanContext;
    }

    private String guestBeanName;

    @Inject
    public void setGuestBeanName(String guestBeanName) {
        this.guestBeanName = guestBeanName;
    }

    public Object getBean() {
        return guestBeanContext.getBean(guestBeanName);
    }
}
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<beans ...>
    ...
    <bean id="myGuestFactory" class="GuestBeanFactory" scope="singleton">
        <property name="guestBeanContext" ref="...get a reference to the guest bean and inject it here" />
        <property name="guestBeanName" value="name-of-this-bean-inside-guestBeanContext"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="myGuestBean" factory-bean="myGuestFactory" factory-method="getBean"/>
    ...
</beans>
```

This way, `guestBeanContext` manages `name-of-this-bean-inside-guestBeanContext`, but the "host" context can access that bean using the name `myGuestBean`.

Comment: Suppose if same bean is defined in applicatoinContext.xml and -servlet.xml then will there be different instances of the same bean or override first one?

Comment: @Jitesh if `applicationContext.xml` and `servlet.xml` are parsed by different `ApplicationContext` instances, then there will be different beans, one inside each `ApplicationContext`. If both files are parsed by the same `ApplicationContext` I think the result is undefined, though the actual result is that the definition that is parsed last overrides the first.